# Type Inference on a function using a parameter

Tags: typescript

I've been fiddling around recently with generic types, and while writing one function I had to determine the return type using one of the parameters from the function.

To give a general idea, here's more or less what I would like to be able to do:

```ts
const getString = () => 'string';

const getNumber = () => 9999;

const getNumberOrString =
    <
        T extends 'number' | 'string',
        ReturnType extends T extends 'number' ? number : T extends 'string' ? string : void
    >(which: T): ReturnType => {
        switch (which) {
            case 'number':
                return getNumber();
            case 'string':
                return getString();
            default:
                return;
        }
    };
```

When running the code above on the Typescript Playground, I run into the following error messages:

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType'.
> 'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'ReturnType', but 'ReturnType' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number'.(2322)

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType'.
> 'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'ReturnType', but 'ReturnType' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number'.(2322)

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType'.
> 'ReturnType' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'undefined'.(2322)

The only way I can get this code running without any errors is by typecasting the return statements to `any`, but is there any other way I can do this without having to resort to typecasting?

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your contribution. For future reference, please [don't post error messages as screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3104399). I've just submitted an edit changing your screenshot to the actual text content of the error messages.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation in TypeScript; the evaluation of conditional types that depend on unspecified generic type parameters is *deferred*, and the compiler doesn't know how to verify that values are assignable to them.

Inside the implementation of `getNumberOrString()`, the generic type parameter `T` is unspecified (it only gets specified upon *calling* `getNumberOrString()`), and so the return type `T extends 'number' ? number : ...` is one of these deferred types.  And so when you try to return any particular value like `return getNumber()`, the compiler is unable to verify that `number` is assignable to that type, and you get an error.

It would be nice if the compiler could use something like control flow analysis to understand that `return getNumber()` can only happen when `T extends 'number'`, but for now that is not the case.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for a feature request to implement support for this and a discussion about why it's not an easy problem to solve.

---

So for now, the only way to write functions with a generic conditional return type is to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (what you're calling "typecasting") or the equivalent (like a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) which allows you to loosen the implementation signature).

Here's how you might write your function:

```
type NumOrStrReturnType<T> = 
  T extends 'number' ? number : 
  T extends 'string' ? string : 
  never;

const getNumberOrString =
    <T extends 'number' | 'string'>(which: T): NumOrStrReturnType<T> => {
        switch (which) {
            case 'number':
                return getNumber() as NumOrStrReturnType<T>;
            case 'string':
                return getString() as NumOrStrReturnType<T>;
            default:
                throw new Error("I DIDN'T EXPECT THAT");
        }
    };
```

Note how `getNumberOrString` has only *one* generic parameter. It looks like you were using the second generic parameter as a way to give a short name to the return type, but it can lead to weird behavior (e.g., it could be specified as a narrower type than intended (e.g., `getNumberOrString<'number',42>('number')`) so I'm avoiding that.  Instead I just gave a type alias for the return type and used it multiple times in type assertions.

Also note how instead of `return` I have thrown an error in the impossible `default` case.  This, by the way, is another limitation of control flow inside generic function implementations.  Even though it is potentially possible for `which` to be narrowed to `never` in that clause, the compiler doesn't even try, because it cannot narrow `T` itself.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) and [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) for the feature requests to support *that*.  You can work around it without the `throw`, but that's going too far afield, I think.

The main point here is that any version of `getNumberOrString()` using generic conditional types will require that you, the implementer, take responsibility for maintaining type safety, since the compiler is not up to the task as of TypeScript 4.1.

---

For the particular function you've written, the only way I know how to write it so that the compiler can actually maintain type safety is to represent the return type as a [property lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types):

```
interface NumOrStr {
    number: number;
    string: string;
}
const getNumberOrString2 =
    <K extends keyof NumOrStr>(which: K): NumOrStr[K] {
        return ({
            get number() { return getNumber() },
            get string() { return getString() }
        })[which];
    }
```

The compiler sees `getNumberOrString2()` as taking a param of type `"number"` or `"string"` and returning a value of type `number` or `string` as if it were looking up a property in an object of type `NumOrStr`.  And the implementation actually does that (via getters).  This works as desired:

```
console.log(getNumberOrString2("number").toFixed(2)); // 9999.00
console.log(getNumberOrString2("string").toUpperCase()); // STRING
const sOrN = getNumberOrString2(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "string" : "number");
// const sOrN: string | number
```

Is it worth jumping through such hoops to get type safety from the compiler?  Probably not.  But it's at least *possible* to do it here, which is nice, I guess.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygZSgJwJZjjAvDACgEo8A+GAcmk2woG4BYAKGdElkSgDkBXAWwBGCNHkIlc5AJzTJjFkygBPAA4IYvPgHk0qNACUkPNGAAqKhAB4T5XMxj2YJmAgAeUBGAAmESmH5C0ChgAfhg-QWEYAC47BydXdy8fKnQsOCDQ6jTo2PswBAA3YTlmVnBoeCQNAO1dbNsmBxgrZzcPb19-YSCAH0os2lICAHcACwxgUajHImmNWvQDKCNTcysbcgBvXKaYCGGMKEnCMYnRkm3G3evgAEMINQpwgIoYq+uPmDRDY0ruLrQxBg93U-AW+h+q1U6zknyadwe-VStDecI+32Wv04dWwQJB8x0i0hZmh1lhaJgngQADNbjwADZQVEUppQUZoEDDMIILkAUTQHMBACIAJIwAAiIvFXAoTl5AA0AAq8gDCThMAAkAIImIVEcnXAC+O0NJSYWHcaFpwDUBN0MEuTWewmmzrQdHsOwGcGm3rkxqYbAqnGqwnBaQATHgdhYANKtRIdADWCEUIGpoK0hLQQ1Ok2msdmmfBAG1YwBdB07JoYlaER0UzhhAFAzZfSF-UOAkiGgA01Y+Te9rfbmLAfxxcCBAc+hqIJbzo3LBpgAbKkBA9IQADp6SApyGAeHsBGCEK3Xrt1AQAAxDAuBCeAgRoj6mAAenfMBkkm3AAY-3XCBNx3PcDyqI9s0jM9vUva8AFVlFUNAVXuBBiDfT8YGQEw9BFLgAHEgNgCBtC4URDwiNBjzgU8AFlbjZbc0FuLwQD4IELBgP9twAVhCGAhVg6JBIvfVmCwoMSLI31kRwPo3VKJggA)